# Close vs closed for door, which one is correct?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

I know that the opposite of 'open' for door is 'closed'. While 'close' means near. But I found a sentence while reading a novel that says:

> He heard the door to the private room **open and close** quietly

I hope someone will help me to understand why the author used **close** instead of **closed** here.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The "active" verb in your context is ***heard*** (which would be conjugated differently in Present Tense, as *He **hears** the door...* The verbs ***open*** and ***close*** are "bare **infinitives**" (base verb form without the "infinitive marker" ***to***). Same as *John shouted*, as opposed to *I heard John shout.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **verbs** are **open** and **close**. I open a door, then I close the door. Doors open and close. The past participles are **opened** and **closed**.

The **adjectives** are **open** and **closed**. The door **is open** or **is closed**.

(Note that "close" can also be an adjective, but with a different meaning, namely the opposite of far. "The door is close" means the door is nearby, not far away. Although spelled the same, it is pronounced differently, with an unvoiced "s" instead of voiced as in "close (the door)".)